# How to change message field format for ResponseEntity?

Tags: java, spring, format, httpresponse

In my Spring-Boot app, my API returns response body using `org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity`

```
Example:
    {
      "timestamp": "Oct 2, 2019 3:24:32 PM",
      "status": 200,
      "error": "OK",
      "message": "Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool",
      "path": "/a/b/c/d/init"
    }
```

I need to change the message field format to a shorten format.

I tried to find it over the web and I found references for other 3rd party lib and not for spring.

In my app I got this Configuration Bean:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.text.DateFormat;

@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.enable(JsonParser.Feature.STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION);
        objectMapper.setDateFormat(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance());

        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to format the message field ?

Comment: did you get your answer?

Comment: no. im still looking for it

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom json serializer in jackson and decide what should be done with particular string value by annotation bean property with `@JsonSerialize(using=SerializerClassName.class)`

```
public class Message{

   @JsonSerialize(using=MessageSerializer.class)
   private String description

//other properties
}
```

```
public class MessageSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        if(value.length() > 70){
            gen.writeString(value.substring(0, 67) + "...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea, is this serializer can be used as a formatter like in dates?

Comment: Yes! It can be. Though in springboot there is a  property in yaml or properties file that allows setting up serialized date format. `spring.jackson.date-format=specify date format`

Comment: Also, @JsonFormat is another annotation that could be used for serializing dates. A nice blog https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-formatting-json-dates